# XPATH get glyphicon glyphicon-star

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to convert glyphicon-star to text in XPATH query ?

I'm trying to write webscraper for rotten tomatoes.

RT review looks like this.

```
<div class="row review_table_row"> 
  <div class="col-xs-8"> 
  ...
  <div class="col-xs-16"> 
      <span style="color:#F1870A" class="fl"> 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      </span> 

  <span class="fr small subtle">May 25, 2018</span> 
  ...
```

But `class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"` is empty so my query doesn't return any text.
Can I replace glyphicon for e.g. "1" ? Or is there any other option how to grab this element in human readable form ?

So far my query is this : `//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-star']`
But returned content is empty.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you want to achieve here. Could you try describing it in a better way?

Comment: Well I'm trying to download structure like {name} {review_score}. 
But review is not defined by any text. It's just multiple 
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>` blocks. 

When I try to query for score, nothing is returned. 

Just for the completeness. I'm using google spreadsheet with formula 

`=transpose(IMPORTXML("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/solo_a_star_wars_story/reviews/?page=1&type=user&sort=","//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-star']"))`

But as I say, nothing is returned. I'm expected to get review score.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then something like this should solve your problem `count(//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'])`

Comment: Oh, great idea. I didn't though about that.Unfortunately it doesn't work. 
"0" is returned. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps the source document is in a namespace?